# Reset android studio appearance settings to default

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Suddenly the UI texts of Android studio became bold (maybe after an inappropriate shutdown). I didn't change font settings for android studio appearance myself. This is how it looks like:

**Before:** [image]

**After:** [image]

I'm on Ubuntu. what's the default font name? (Although as you may see I haven't ticked the customization option in setting)

How to reset only the **appearance settings** to the default? (not gradle settings, build and compile settings, etc)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29432109/intellij-idea-bold-fonts-after-update-to-14-1 this helped me.

Comment: @ashishsony Thanks. I used that to make AS environment similar to the past. Although I haven't got what was the reason for this event. Do you know, by any chance, if the __DjaVu Sans__ is the default font of AS?

Comment: I dont know for sure if DjaVu Sans is the default, but SansSerif with 14 font, seems the closest to default to me.

Answer (score 0):

The default font in Ubuntu is "Ubuntu". From Wikipedia: "The Ubuntu Font Family is the default font for the current and development releases of the Ubuntu operating system and is used for the Ubuntu project branding."

So I'd start by overriding "default" fonts, ticking that box, and selecting the 14 point Ubuntu font that's greyed out. :-)